status of 404 (Not Found) after deploy my React Vite project to AWS S3

This is a portfolio site. I used couple libraries in the projects and lots of images. I also deployed the project to github pages a while ago. Would this be the reason I get 404 status? I'm super new to AWS, try to learn by deploying some small projects. The first time, I just dragged all files inside dist directory( I believe React will be build)after npm run build. Second, I tried to import from Github through CodePipeline. I also put the index document and error document as index.html Both are not working. How can I fix this issue?

I ran into similar trouble with vite the solution seems to be tweaking your vite.config.js
firstly you need to set your base to './' in your vite config and then in build options of the config set your assetsDir to './'
This seems to have resolved my issues now the index.html is pointed correctly to built .js file
here is my vite.config.js hope it helps
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        port: 3000,
    },
    build: {
        outDir: './build',
        assetsDir: './',
    },
    base: './',
});

